# Redshift - How can I coalesce and add along the row dimension?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

How can I coalesce and maybe add vertically? Say I have a table such as:

```
| NAME   | Metric1 | Metric2 | Metric3 | Metric4 |
|--------|---------|---------|---------|---------|
| class1 | NULL    | 3       | NULL    | 4       |
| class1 | 1       | NULL    | 4       | NULL    |
| class2 | 5       | 2       | 6       | NULL    |
| class2 | NULL    | NULL    | 1       | NULL    |
| class2 | 4       | NULL    | NULL    | NULL    |
```

with 2 classes(`class` and `class2`. Sometimes a metric will be NULL, and sometimes it will be populated. I would like an end result like so:

```
| NAME   | Metric1 | Metric3 | Metric3 | Metric4   |
|--------|---------|---------|---------|-----------|
| class1 | 1       | 3       | 4       | 4         |
| class2 | 9       | 2       | 7       | NULL or 0 |
```

where the results are grouped by class name, and the metrics are "coalesced" if only 1 instance is populated or added if multiple are. Any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `sum()`:

```
select name, sum(metric1), sum(metric2), sum(metric3), sum(metric4)
from t
group by name;
```

Comment: Thanks. I was confused as to how to implement this if my first table is actually derived from aggregations, that is if my metrics are results of aggregations, because I don't think nested aggregations/windows are allowed. But I put it in a CTE and then just did this.

Comment: @Alex . . . You can ask another question about fixing your first query.  You should be able to just fix the aggregation.